# Change Indy10 TCP ServerExecute thread priority for faster speed of execution?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy, lazarus

Normally when using Delphi/Lazarus threads it is possible to change the priority of the thread so that it can execute faster.

That said, is it possible to do the same for the Indy10 TCP Server component? If so, how? Is it even advisable to do so?

thanks

Comment: There's next-to-no point as, no doubt, Remy will soon be telling you too:)  Threads don't automatically execute faster just because their priority has been raised.  Why do you need 'faster execution' - what is the actual problem?

Comment: If computers could just be made to go faster by turning up the volume, don't you think they would come out of the box already turned up to full volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` uses normal Delphi/Lazarus threads.

If you are running on Windows, you can call the Win32 API `GetCurrentThread()` and `SetThreadPriority()` functions.  Or, you can set the priority of a `TThread` object using Indy's `SetThreadPriority()` (Indy 9 and earlier) or `IndySetThreadPriority()` (Indy 10) function.

If you are using a modern Delphi version, you can use the `TThread.CurrentThread` property to get a `TExternalThread` object representing the calling thread.  `TExternalThread` is a `TThread` descendant, so it can be passed to `IndySetThreadPriority()`, or you can just set the `TThread.Priority` property directly.

If you want to access Indy's own `TThread` objects directly, it can be done, depending on which version of Indy you are using:

If you are using Indy 9 and earlier, the server events provide a `TIdPeerThread` object pointer. `TIdPeerThread` is a `TThread` descendant.  Simple enough.

If you are using Indy 10, on the other hand, it goes out of its way to hide/abstract the threads away from you.  The server events now provide a `TIdContext` object pointer, and `TIdContext` is not the thread itself.  But all is not lost.  If the `TIdTCPServer.Scheduler` property is pointing at a `TIdSchedulerOfThread`-derived component (`TIdTCPServer` uses `TIdSchedulerOfThreadDefault` internally if you do not provide a `Scheduler`), then you can type-cast the `TIdContext.Yarn` property to a `TIdYarnOfThread` object pointer and then access the `TIdYarnOfthread.Thread` property, which is a `TIdThreadWithTask` object pointer.  `TIdThreadWithTask` is a `TThread` descendant.